# PyQt4. Как установить имя и размер шрифта в QWebView?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Открываю страницу с помощью QWebView, в классе WcgWebView пытаюсь установить имя и размер шрифта, но это игнорируется PyQt4. Что я делаю не так?

```
class WcgWebView(QWebView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WcgWebView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.settings().setFontFamily(QWebSettings.StandardFont, 'Times New Roman')
        self.settings().setFontSize(QWebSettings.DefaultFontSize, 12)
```

Comment: [`w.setFont(QFont("Times", 25, QFont.Normal))` работает](https://gist.github.com/zed/62227e5e360fd2a5316c74af9497f42b)

Comment: Это и у меня работает. У меня не устанавливается размер и шрифт в QWebView на странице.